# How to apply vignette image magick filter in ez publish

Tags: imagemagick, ezpublish

Hi Im using eZ Publish and wish to apply a vignette filter to a image, how I am not sure how to do so in the image.ini file.

At the moment I have

```
[frontitem]
Reference=
Filters[]
Filters[]=geometry/scaleexact=800;400
```

However Im not sure how to add it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
convert input.png -background none -vignette 0x30+10+10 output.png
```